# How can I prevent a large and frequent FTP download from ruining my entire internet connection?

Tags: java, download, ftp

After following this tutorial(http://www.codejava.net/java-se/networking/ftp/how-to-download-a-complete-folder-from-a-ftp-server), and also programming the same thing in Python, both of the programs cause horrible lag on my internet connection.

I've tried limiting my byte size in python which did nothing, and I've been unable to implement a similar Java byte size reduction. I've also tried adding a sleep timer between downloads to no avail.

I have 250mbit service, and my FTP download speed is 1.2Mb/s. That should leave me with ~230mbits for the rest of my internet connection. When I do the same transfer through FileZilla, there is no issue on my internet connection.

What can I do to prevent the download from pulling so much bandwidth, especially when it is supposedly only going at 1.2Mb/s?

Comment: Please include a minimal example of your python code that still causes the performance issue.

Comment: I'm not interested in fixing my python code, I just wanted to see if the problem was recreated in another language. I'd much prefer help with my Java code, which is in the link at the top

Comment: If you are using the code that uses the for loop you could put a small sleep in between files to give your internet connection a breather so that the ftp process doesn't dominate your bandwidth 100%.

Comment: @mba12 Will this help during the download of the files themselves? They're 200Mb+ each so a sleep between each one doesn't seem like it would help much

Comment: @Nexion21 Perhaps instead find an ftp client that will throttle the connection speed and slow it down. That would work better than writing your own code from scratch and injecting sleep pauses.